# How to copy a dynamically allocated object (with having one const member of a class)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, c++17, c++14

I'm trying to make a function, where user can add an entry in the data, so the array dynamically increases it's size by 1 and allows the user to enter the data.

Logic:

1. pass the current size and array pointer by reference to a function
2. make a new pointer array (dynamically allocated) in the function, and increase it size by 1 .
3. copy all the data from the passed array to newly made array
4. delete the memory allocated to parameter pointer
5. point the parameter pointer to new pointer array.

Problem: I have a const int member in the class,following the algorithm above, when I try to copy contents to new pointer,it's obvious that id would'nt be copied to const member.
I have a hunch that I can use copy constructor here with a initialization list, and initialize the new array of the function with the help of copy constructor.

I need to know how to copy a dynamically allocated object array using copy constructor and moreover, if the object have some const member.

Thanks in advance.

CLASS HEADER:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class ramish
{
private:
    const int id;
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << "ID = " << id;
    }
    ramish():id(rand()%100+1)
    {
    }
    //ramish(ramish *& object)
    //{
    //}
};
```

FUNCTION AND DRIVER:

```
int main()
{
   int size = 4;
   ramish* object = new ramish[size];
   copypointer(object, size);
}

void copypointer(ramish*& object, int size)
{
   ramish *newobject = new ramish[size + 1];
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       newobject[i]=object[i];//going to give error here due to const member
   }
   delete[]object;
   //take inps from user for newobject[size]
   object = newobject;
   newobject = NULL;
}
```

Comment: "I can use copy constructor here with a initialization list" did you try that? The simple solution is to make the member not `const`. Anyhow there is no way to modify it from outside, as it is `private` already.

Comment: yes I did but I'm facing issues in copying the pointer array sing copy constructor

Comment: We can assign a value to const member at time of the declaration of the object using initialization list, as in the case above, I'm doing that. than there must be a way I think that that can loop down the parameter pointer index while at copy constructor copies the paramter pointer to newpointer.

Comment: not sure what you mean. `object = newobject;` is copying a pointer, that has nothing to do with the copy constructor. If you have an issue with a compiler error in your code, please include the compiler error in the question.

Comment: I have found that a useful rule of thumb is, "when you think you want a const member, think a little more".

Comment: You can't accomplish that with arrays - the copy constructor is only used for initialization, so you would need to pass an initializer list in the new-expression, but you can't enumerate the elements you want to copy since the size is dynamic. `std::vector` already does what you need, so why duplicate it?

Answer (score 0):

> I can use copy constructor here with a initialization list

Yes you can:

```
class ramish
{
private:
    const int id;
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout << "ID = " << id << "\n";
    }
    ramish():id(rand()%100+1)
    {
    }
    ramish(const ramish& other) : id(other.id)
    {
    }
};

int main() {
    ramish a;
    ramish b = a;
    a.print();
    b.print();
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/5Pr6Mb1Mq):

```
ID = 84
ID = 84
```

Though you should consider to remove the `const` from the member. Why did you make it `const`? So that it cannot be modified. But it is private and from outside the class there is no way to modify it even when it is not `const`. Then you can rely on the compiler generated copy constructor ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/sEjhYxav1)).

Comment: Thanks , but what if I had a dynamic array and I had to copy the whole list of data from it, that's where I'm stucked.

Comment: @QaziZainullah `std::vector<ramish> a; std::vector<ramish> b = a;` its really that simple. If you want to go the c-array route you need to copy "by hand" which you can do once you have a working copy constructor (or `memcpy`)